# Vue components without webpack/npm/yarn

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I know with vue-cli importing components is really simple. However, would it be possible to import components to a vue project that is not using vue-cli?

For example my index.html would look like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Vue components</title>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.16/dist/vue.js">  </script>
    <script src="https://github.com/mdbootstrap/Vue-Bootstrap-with-Material-Design/archive/mdbvue.js">  </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="vue-app">
      <Btn color="danger">Test Button</Btn>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

And my app.js:

```
import { Btn } from 'mdbvue'

new Vue({
  el: '#vue-app',
  components: {
    Btn
  },
  data: {
  }
}
```

If it would not be as simple as my example is there a tutorial somewhere to figure out how to get this working without using npm or yarn?

Thanks

Comment: Have a look at the [async components documentation](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-dynamic-async.html#Async-Components), specifically the use of the [`import()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import#Dynamic_Import) syntax. The latter should help you dynamically load a component into your Vue application.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It might be bit late however I believe in better late than never!!

I came across the simillar situation where I do not want to use any build tool as I feel those build tools are bit of overkill.

There is a js plugin you could give it a go. (I have not used it though as we moved to AngularJS + TypeScript + Visual Studio 2017 - which met our requirement).

**Plugin**: **http-vue-loader**

**Link** : https://github.com/FranckFreiburger/http-vue-loader

**Example** : on codepen dot io /cscolabear/project/editor/AQLQLO

**Requirements**

- Vue.js 2 (compiler and runtime)
- es6-promise (optional, except for IE, Chrome < 33, FireFox < 29, ... )
- webserver (optional)...

**How it works**

- http request the vue file
- load the vue file in a document fragment
- process each section (template, script and style)
- return a promise to Vue.js (async components)
- then Vue.js compiles and cache the component

**Notes**

The aim of http-vue-loader is to quickly test .vue components without any compilation step.
However, for production, I recommend to use webpack module bundler with vue-loader, webpack-simple is a good minimalist webpack config you should look at.
BTW, see also why Vue.js doesn't support templateURL.

**Caveat**

Due to the lack of suitable API in Google Chrome and Internet Explorer, syntax errors in the  section are only reported on FireFox.

**Credits** : [Franck Freiburger](https://www.franck-freiburger.com/)

Comment: Does it also allow variables to interact with each other between components?

Comment: Just note that Vue3 support is also available through https://github.com/FranckFreiburger/vue3-sfc-loader

Answer (score 1):

`import { Btn } from 'mdbvue'`

From the codes u posted, u already have used es6 modules. So at least you should use webpack with babel-loader, otherwise, the browser will not support the grammar above.

Comment: Sorry I meant to say that was the way that I would import in vue-cli but I would like a way to do it similarly without vue-cli